# color listview line with condition android/java

Tags: java, android, listview, background-color

I'm searching to get a little useful option to my app, the basics are simple, I have a list of questions (in listView) when we click in the question, we have another activity with details of questions and the answer that is setting ( true or false), if the answer is right, I want to color the question in the listview in green, red if false:

My code to generate questions:

```
public void showQuest(View view){
        ModelHelper md = new  ModelHelper(this);
        db = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        Spinner s = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spn_ques);
        Integer para = 2;
        para = Integer.parseInt( s.getSelectedItem().toString())  ;
        ArrayList<String> lstQ = md.getOnlyQuestions(para);
        ArrayAdapter lstad = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,lstQ);
        lst.setAdapter(lstad);
```

The listView OnclickListener:

```
String quest = (String) parent.getAdapter().getItem(i);
                int pos = lst.getCheckedItemPosition();

                Intent inte = new Intent(view.getContext(),Reponse.class);



                cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+ ModelHelper.TABLE_QUESTION + " WHERE " + ModelHelper.KEY_QUESTION + " = ? ",new String[] {quest});
                if (cursor != null)
                    if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {

                    cursor.moveToFirst();

                        final Intent intent = getIntent();
                   String matr=     intent.getStringExtra("id");



                    String repA = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ModelHelper.KEY_PROFIL_WAITEDANSWER));
                    String cible = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ModelHelper.KEY_PROFILE));
                    String plan = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ModelHelper.KEY_PLAN));
                    int ID = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(ModelHelper.KEY_ID_QUESTION));

                    inte.putExtra("Question", quest);
                    inte.putExtra("answ", repA);
                    inte.putExtra("ID", ID);
                    inte.putExtra("pos", pos);
                    inte.putExtra("position", i);
                    inte.putExtra("matr", matr);


                        Toast.makeText(new.this, "" + ID, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    startActivity(inte);



                }
                }

        });
```

The answer is selected in another activity, in the first one I have only the questions' list.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you are rendering the item in the listview set the background color based on the logic you described.

Comment: if I do it when I select I can't because I answer in the next Activity, then I back to the activity with the listView